# full featured XMPP web client

Tags: client, xmpp

Hi I wanted to know is there any  full featured XMPP web client(like conversejs) available on the net?

I want it to have group management at least!

if this question does not relate to stackoverflow please forward it to the appropriate forum.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen http://candy-chat.github.io/candy/?
It is focused on real-time multi-user chatting.

Comment: yes. but i want to create member only rooms. and I couldn't find such a feature in it! thanks BTW.

Comment: I believe that "member-only rooms" is a configuration of the xmpp server. <img src="https://www.evernote.com/shard/s23/sh/0c0ad6e8-fb5c-4b65-b31b-a3e143a40c64/e497ec19fb34313fbc07ab711706aba2" width="100" height="100"/>

Comment: "This project is dead and not maintained anymore" https://github.com/candy-chat/candy

Answer (score 0):

Its old threat but still if anyone looking for XMPP javascript client

Then you can use [Stanza.io](https://github.com/legastero/stanza)

You will get response in json so easily use with JS

Also support almost XEP's